# I created a blockchain api and ran it, I verified it in postman and it's working fine but while parsing the body its giving me numerous errors

Tags: json, express, npm

[This image is of the api.js file I've created.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MqNjF.png)

[In Postman i am providing body part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFCLL.png)

[Then everything is printed in console but even I change console.log to res.send its giving me same error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPToh.png)

Comment: Please edit your question and add code-snippets instead of images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `'transactions'`-handler you are calling `res.send()` twice. You can only do this once, so change it to e.g.

```
app.post('/transactions', (req,res) => {
    res.send(`The amount ... is ${req.body.amount}...`);
})
```

Comment: Yes got it, thank you so much. It's working fine now.

Comment: Happy to help, make sure not to forget to accept the answer. Thanks :)